# understanding positioning < a > elements wrapped inside < div > parent

Tags: html, css

I don`t understand why:

1. **vertical-align** - doesn't work in this case, although the elements are set along a baseline and are inline elements. I've tried without float but that's not the case. Why doesn't it work, what am i missing?
2. What decides how `<a>`'s are positioned inside this **DIV**?
3. I'm creating a breakdown moment, and thinking of a way to position `<a>`'s (those with icons) below the `<a>`'s with logo-main class. Using CSS. I've changed `<a>`'s display to block - but that didn't brought them below.

[image]

```css
.back-green {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
}

.logo-main {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.fa-book,
.fa-compact-disc {
  font-size: 150%;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.rr {
  float: right;
  padding: 11px;
}
```

```html
<div class="back-green">
  <a class="logo-main">KSIAZKI&DVD</a>
  <a class="rr"><i class="fas fa-compact-disc shad-logo2 "></i></a>
  <a class="rr"><i class="fas fa-book shad-logo2 va"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: add your HTML Code & Screenshot what you want

Comment: added. questions are mostly theoretical , trying to understand basics but cant find the answers.

Answer (score 0):

By your screenshot what I understood is, You want these two icons under your logo, and right now these are going right to LOGO,

This is because you gave float:right to these logo.

I have removed this. change structure a little bit.

If this is not what you want just let me know where you want the location of these icons.

1.vertical-align - doesn't work in this case, although the elements are set along a baseline and are inline elements. Ive tried without float but thats not the case. Why doesnt it work, what am i missing?

**vertical-align aligns the inline elements with each other, it doesn't position them within their container.**

2. What decides how < a >`s are positioned inside this **DIV**?

Any element by default took the position where it is kept in your code depending on its nature of Display (Block, inline). by Default float is none. So if you have three Anchor tags and no float then they will come side by side(inline),
and if you will gave them float-right property then these will float to their right.

3. In your case these will not be coming below logo due to float right, there are 2 anchors which have float right, so it will always float right no matter what display you have assigned to those.

```css
.back-green {max-width: 600px; margin: auto;}
.logo-main {padding: 10px; font-size: 40px;}
.fa-book, .fa-compact-disc {font-size: 150%; padding-top: 5px;}
.rr {padding: 11px;}  
.text-center {text-align:center;}
```

```html
<div class="back-green">
      <div class="text-center"><a class="logo-main">KSIAZKI&DVD</a></div>
      <div class="text-center"><a class="rr"><i class="fas fa-compact-disc shad-logo2 ">Flopy</i></a>
      <a class="rr"><i class="fas fa-book shad-logo2 va">CD</i></a></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: *`Vertical align does not work on Inline elements. It will work in table or on inline-block elements`* can you please point to some documentation that supports your bolded statement?

Comment: I think I have written it too much direct, 

I mean by this is

vertical-align aligns the inline elements with each other, it doesn't position them within their container., Correcting in answer also.

Comment: You understood and pointed that `float-right` is the cause, but missed to explain why. *`It will always float right`* is not an explanation of what happens under the hood.

Comment: Hi @RokoC.Buljan, I would love to read the right explanation for what happens under the hood, if you can explain this for me . Thanks in advance

Comment: **Collapsing**. Where parent collapses height due inner floated elements. The only height accounted by the parent in OP's case will be any other element/s but the floated  `.rr` (in this case the `.logo-main` element). A simple solution for `flex`, or by using other well known *tricks* like **clearfix**, `overflow: auto`, etc...

Comment: gentlemen thank you for answers. 1. yes - i want to align the inline elements (anchor) with each other. That`s why it puzzles me why vertical align - when attached in CSS to anchors - doesn't take any effect. After applying vertical aliment, inline elements should be changing they positions in relation to each other. They DONT. Why? Even when i delete floating. 3. Im trying to create a responsive design – and through media queries  - do a breakout point, when those two icons go under the main logo. Is there a way of doing it by applying CSS to elements?